# If $E\subset \mathbb{R}$ is bounded then $x=\sup E$ is in $\overline{E}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, proof-verification

Please let me know if you think my proof is rigorous enough.

Notation: $\overline{E}$ - the closure of E; $\partial E$ - the boundary of $E$; $E^\circ$ - the interior of $E$.

If $E$ is closed then $E=\overline{E}$, which implies that for any $y\in E$, $y\le \sup E \in E$.
If $E$ is not closed then $\overline{E} = E^\circ \cup \partial E$, so that $\partial E$ contains the endpoint(s) of $E$. Hence, the endpoints of $E$ are contained in $\overline{E}$, and $x\in \overline{E}$.

Comment: It's not true. Consider $[0,1)$. Your hypothesis doesn't say that $E$ is closed. In your 2nd to last line, you conclude that the boundary contains "the endpoint(s) of $E$". Which endpoints are those? There might be infinitely many candidates. I can't follow your last line.

Comment: Then $0 \in \overline{E}$ and $1\in \overline{E}$. Please clarify what is exactly not true.

Comment: What are you trying to prove? That $\sup E \in E$? or that $\sup E\in \overline{E}$? It seems from the title and your last line that you're assuming $E = \overline{E}$ but nowhere do you say that $E$ is closed.

Comment: Sorry, I noticed the typo in the header. Yes, in $\overline{E}$.

Comment: In any case, this talk of "endpoints" is mistaken. Consider $\{n/(n+1)\mid n\in \Bbb N\}$. $\sup E = 1$ but it's not an "endpoint" of any subset of $E$.

Comment: At this stage any proof that does not explicitly use the defining property of sup is not rigorous enough.

Comment: Agree with BrianO - the "endpoint" is not rigorous. Not sure what is your definition of "endpoint". It is much better to use the fact the sup E is in fact a limit point of E and therefore in the closure.

Comment: Can you see that $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)\cap E$? It's trivial to proof by contradiction. This is basically the whole proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm confused by your proof, but the fact that you don't use the definition of sup is probably a sign you're not being rigorous enough.

Here's a simple proof that uses limit points:

Let $\sup E = a$ and let $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Then $\exists e_n\in E$ such that $a-e_n<\frac{1}{n}$, as otherwise $a-1/n$ would be an upper bound of $E$ that's less than $a$. Then the sequence $\{e_n\}$ converges to $a$ and so $a$ is a limit point of $E$, so it falls in the closure of $E$.

Here's the same idea but without limit points:

Let $\sup E = a$ and let $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Then $\exists e_n\in E$ such that $a-e_n<\frac{1}{n}$, as otherwise $a-1/n$ would be an upper bound of $E$ that's less than $a$. Fix $\epsilon>0$. Notice that $\exists N$ such that $\epsilon>1/N$. Thus $e_N\in B_\epsilon(x)$. But this ball clearly contains a point in $E^c$, because it contains a point larger than $x$, and $x=\sup E$.

Comment: OK that's true now:) But I'd still phrase it $\exists e_n\in E$ s.t. $a-1/n \le e_n$.

Comment: @BrianO fixed it, thanks. The inequality is fine, but the "otherwise" comment is not

Comment: @StellaBiderman: we haven't yet covered the concept of limit points. I'm wondering how can one argue that $x\in \overline{E}$ on the basis that $\sup E = x$?

Comment: @sequence What is your definition of the boundary and the closure then?

Comment: Boundary: the set of all points $x$ such that $B_r(x)\cap E \ne \emptyset \ne B_r(x)\cap E^c$.
Closure: the intersection of all sets in $R^n$ containing the set $E$. Alternatively, the closure is the union of the interior and the boundary.

Comment: @sequence I edited it to prove it using your definition.

Comment: Also, I think you're missing a "$\forall r$" there.

Comment: @StellaBiderman: thank you. Are you using the Approximation principle in your proof? This approach seems somewhat different than what I know.

Comment: What's the approximation principle? I'm using the fact that for every positive real number, there is a number set than it of the form $1/n$. This is a consequence of (among other things) the Archemedian Principle applied to $1/\epsilon$

Comment: I'm wondering if I can say that if we set $0<\varepsilon<1$ so that $\sup E + \varepsilon = x$ then $s < x$ and $0 < x-s < 1$. Set $h:=1/(x-s)$ and $g=1$, then, by Archimedean pricnciple, $\exists n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $h < ng \iff 1/(x-s) < n \iff 1/n < x-s \iff 1/n - x < s \iff s < x-1/n < x$. Since $(x-1/n) \in E$, $s \geq x - 1/n$ by def. of $\sup E$. Then we arrive at a contradiction. Hence, $\sup E = x$, and $x\in \overline{E}$. The only thing is that I'm concerned about the implication that $x\in\overline{E}$. This might not be rigorous enough.

Comment: You never show in that proof that $x\in\overline{E}$. But this looks needlessly complicated, and it surprises me you've never seen an approach like mind before.

Comment: At my current level I seem to need to take more time to understand your proof, thus I'm trying to "adapt" it to something which uses concepts we've covered so far.

Comment: @sequence why not ask a question about a piece you don't understand?

Comment: @StellaBiderman: the part "Notice that ∃N such that ϵ>1/N. Thus $e_N  \in B_ϵ(x)$, and what follows thereafter.

Comment: @sequence $1/\epsilon$ is a finite real number and so there is a natural number greater than it. That natural number has inverse smaller than $\epsilon$. I previously built a sequence of numbers that get very close (and in fact converge) to $x$, and by construction $e_N$ is within $1/N$ of $x$.

Answer (score 1):

For a proof to be rigorous, one necessary condition is that all the terms used in it are precisely defined (whether by you or by previous mathematicians). Now what is "endpoint" supposed to mean? I can't think of any reasonable definition that sounds like "endpoint". Like what are the endpoints of $\{ x : x \in (0,1) \land x \in \mathbb{Q} \}$? And once you fix the definition of "endpoint" you're stuck with it and have to prove whatever 'fact' you use concerning "endpoints".

Answer (score 0):

The result follows closely from (a) the definition of closure of E.

Let sup(E) = UB and consider an open ball B(U,r) around UB.  This open set must contain points of E, for if this were not the case, we could find a value of r such that B(U,r) contains no points of E,  so we can reduce the upper bound to UB-r, so this would contradict the assumption that UB is sup(E).  Hence, any open set around sup(E) would contain points of E, this is the definition of membership of the closure of E.